# How to set one field's value equal to the concatenation of other two fields value

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have three field in backend:-

```
productCode: {type : String, required: true, index: true},
value: String,
productInternal: {type : String, required: true, index: true, unique: true}
```

I want to set productInternal field value equal to concatenation of other two:
  `valueproductCode`.

The 'value' and 'product code' is given by user:-

```
<select ng-model="a.productCode" name="" ng-options="pc for pc in productCodes">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
</select>

<select  ng-model="a.value" name="" ng-options="v for v in value">
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

The third field `productInternal` is hidden field not to shown to user.

While calling the add segment API, I have to set productInternal field as the concatenation of the value and productCode,

```
ApiServices.addProduct(scope.a).then(function (response) {
                 console.log('added');
            scope.notify('success', response.data);
        }
```

any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 scope.a.productInternal=scope.a.value+scope.a.productCode;

ApiServices.addProduct(scope.a).then(function (response) { console.log('added'); scope.notify('success', response.data); }
```

Comment: From where do u call the api? Directive or controller?

Comment: I am calling the api from directive

Comment: (function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('App.components')
        .directive('product', product);
    product.$inject = ['$http', '$timeout','ApiServices'];
    function product($http, $timeout,  ApiServices) {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope: {
            },
            link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
             scope.a = {};
             scope.cr = false;
          };
         },
            templateUrl: 'js/components/pr/product.html'
        };
    }
})();

Comment: In this code , I can't see tha api calling part. Make sure u call the api only after user selects values from both drop downs.

Comment: scope.conct = function () {
     scope.a.productInternal=scope.a.value+scope.a.productCode; };
   scope.Save = function (isValid) {console.log('save');
      if (isValid){
        if (!scope.cr) {
        ApiServices.updateProduct(scope.a).then(function (response) {});
      } else{
      ApiServices.addProduct(scope.a).then(function (response) {});
         }
       }else{
       scope.notify('error', 'Validation Error: There are errors on the form.); } };   scope.handleAddNew = function () {
       scope.a = { status: false };
        scope.cr = true;
        scope.conct(); };

Comment: Inside handleAddNew function ,you are setting scope.a={status:false}......this will clear the existing values stored in variable a....instead try "scope.a.status=false"

Comment: Thanks @Sreehari S

Answer (score 0):

```
// "+ ''": optional; it's just to enforce concatenation instead of summing, just in case two fields are numeric.
$scope.a.productInternal = $scope.a.value + '' + $scope.a.productCode;

ApiServices.addProduct($scope.a).then(function (response) {
             console.log('added');
        scope.notify('success', response.data);
    }
```